# When migrating to rxjs 6 gulp build.bundle.rxjs throws error

Tags: angular, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-compat

I am upgrading from rxjs 5.5 to 6.2.1. I went through the code base and made all the changes suggested in the rxjs migration document, changed imports, piping instead of chaining, etc. When I run my `npm install` the `build.bundle.rxjs` script throws an error on fetch for rxjs-compat and says it is loading rxjs/Rx, which I can find no reference to in my code base. Has anyone else seen similar problems when upgrading their rxjs?

EDIT:

I found that the source of the error is coming from various packages inside of my node_modules. They are using the deprecated import paths.

Comment: having the same issue ..How did You fix it ? Can You paste an answer ?

Comment: @ClaudioFerraro the problem was so much more than the issue highlighted above. The project was a crazy amalgamation of Angular Seed and Angular CLI. So I spun up a brand new, clean, Angular CLI project and migrated our code into the project and installed packages as needed.